# Finding total sales algebraically

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, rational-functions

A company finds that its sales since the company started in 2000 can be modeled by the function

$s(t)=(20t^2+800t+300)/(8t^2+10t+100)$

where $s$ is the total sales, in millions of dollars, and t is the number of years since 2000.

Calculate the years when sales are 9 million, algebraically.

What I understand from the question is that I need to solve for $t$ when $s(t)=9$. However, I get two answers (positive and negative). How do I rewrite these answers to model the number of years? Also, how do I use this model to predict what sales would be like after many years?

Comment: A negative answer would be a *mathematical* solution that you would ignore, because it doesn’t make sense in the context of the problem.

Comment: Not following.  Negative $t$ doesn't make sense, since that would correspond to a time before the company started.

Comment: Also, you can input whatever value of $t$ you like to get the sales after any number of years.

Comment: wait I'm not following :/

Comment: The current form of the function was my first guess, but that also has the strange property that the sales were 3 million on the zeroth day, and asymptotically tend to 2.5 million as $t\to\infty$? Of course, the "model" is not necessarily realistic :-) @Zerdays, please check that function.

Comment: The function is exactly how it is written on my sheet. I am not sure how to go about this

Answer (score 1):

Double check your solution - no negative!
$$s(t)=\frac{20t^2+800t+300}{8t^2+10t+100}=9
\Rightarrow 52t^2-710t+600=0 \Rightarrow \\
t_{1,2}=\frac{355\pm \sqrt{3793}}{52}\approx 0.9; 12.7.$$
Can you figure out the years starting from $2000$?

Also, note that if in another problem you get a negative number for time, you can ignore it and accept only the positive, that is meaningful numbers!